# Title: Read contents from text file dynamically in classic asp

Tags: asp-classic

I have done the code to write the values I enter in the text box to a text file. Now I want to read those values and assign it to a variable.

The values stored in text file are as follows:

```
abc.jpg,www.google.com
123.jpg, www.yahoo.com
```

I want to read the image name in a separate variable and the link in separate variable. As I want to assign those to image rotator code. Please help.

I have used the following code to read the link in the text file: now I want to read the image name from the text file.

```
Do While Not objTextFile.AtEndOfStream     
    intLineNumber = intLineNumber + 1
    strReadLineText = objTextFile.ReadLine

    'response.Write("Hi")

    Postion1= InStr(strReadLineText, strSearchText)
    Postion2= Postion1 + len(strSearchText)    
    URLString=Mid(strReadLineText,Postion2+1,len(strReadLineText))       
    'URLString=Left(strReadLineText,strSearchText)

    If strSearchText <> "" And InStr(strReadLineText, strSearchText) > 0 Then

        strReadLineText = Replace(strReadLineText, _       
        strSearchText, _
        "<span style=""background-color:yellow;"">" & strSearchText & "</span>")

        strLineNumbers = strLineNumbers & intLineNumber & ", "
Exit Do
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `InStr`, you could use a `Split` ([DevGuru link](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/vbscript/13973.asp)) which will return an array of the values on each line.

```
arrVals = Split(strReadLineText, ",")

strImageName = Trim(arrVals(0))
URLString = Trim(arrVals(1))
```